# orthogonal projection of a vector in a Hilbert space.

Tags: functional-analysis

If {$e_k$} is an orthonormal system of vectors in a Hilbert space $H$, $Y_n=$span{$e_k$} $k=1,...,n$ and $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n(x,e_k)e_k, x\in H$. How to show that $S_n$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $Y_n$.

My attempt: Since $Y_n$ is a subspace so every $x \in H$ can be uniquely written as $x=m+n$ where $m=\sum_{k=1}^n(m,e_k)e_k$ and $n \perp Y_n$. So,

$x=\sum_{k=1}^n(m,e_k)e_k+n$

Since $n \perp Y_n$, for any $y=\sum_{k=1}^n(y,e_k)e_k$, we have $(n,y)=0$

we get,

$(x,\sum_{k=1}^n(y,e_k)e_k)-(\sum_{k=1}^n(m,e_k)e_k,\sum_{k=1}^n(y,e_k)e_k)=0$

which reduces to

$\sum_{k=1}^n[(x-m,e_k)(y,e_k)]$   which is true for any $y$, Can i conclude $x=y$? and how to proceed?

Comment: Hint: what's the action of $S_n$ on the basis vectors?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $S_n$ is the orthogonal projection of $x$ onto $Y_n$ iff 
$$
  (x-S_n,e_k) = 0 \qquad k=1,\dots,n
$$